# Send log to stdout in a Unity app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, console

I'm building a headless server app in Unity.  I'd like it to print status messages to stdout.  But instead it directs all console output to the player log.  This is true even when I try to recover the standard output stream thusly:

```
    StreamWriter standardOutput = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
    standardOutput.AutoFlush = true;
    Console.SetOut(standardOutput);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Server started (this is Console output).");
```

The output there still appears in the player log, and not on the command line where I launch the app (with the -batchmode and -nographics options).  (This was tested on macOS.)

Is there any way to print to standard out from a headless Unity app?

Answer (score 2):

By default Unity doesn't send log to the standard out. To make it do that on macOs, pass `-logfile` as argument to your Unity app when opening it or to the Unity Editor if that's your target. *Don't provide file name to this argument.*

Just add empty `-logfile` argument and it will make Unity send logs to sdout.

For example:

```
TheApp.app/Contents/MacOS/TheApp -batchmode -nographics -logfile
```

Comment: Thank you, that's better than nothing, but not what I was asking for.  I didn't want to redirect *all* log output, but only specific messages.  Is there really no way to do that?

Comment: Nope. It doesn't look  like you can in Unity. You can either print all of them or none at-all